# How to request full access when sign in using near-js

Tags: nearprotocol, near

I've got a problem with signing in using near-js. I just call wallet.requestSignIn and it works but always I see that application request Limited access. There is nothing about Limited and Full access in documentation so I just guess that I should do something to request Full access

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep your wallet secure, a web app signing in to NEAR should not request full access keys.

Instead you ask for an access key to the smart contract your web app is going to use, and you can also specify which method names on the contract that should be allowed calling ( see the `methodNames` property of the [SigninOptions](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/7ea21f330af1a00543b1ae655761a98820f6a368/lib/wallet-account.d.ts#L8) )